# Process.Start Permissions Problem

Tags: c#, .net, latex, processstartinfo

I'm trying to run an external problem from C# by using Process.Start, but am running into permissions issues.  When I open a command prompt normally (not as an admin) and run my commands they work fine, but when I open a command prompt via Process.Start, I get a write error on the directory.  ("I can't write on file test.log")
If I run it as an admin via Process.Start it works fine, but I get the permissions popup. Does anyone have any ideas that might help me figure this out?  Thanks!

Here is the code I'm using:

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"cmd.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/k latex C:\Users\Shane\Documents\test.tex";
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Why do you need to wrap your program thru cmd.exe?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wonder whether it's trying to write a diagnostic log to the current working directory, which you may not have permissions for. (I don't know offhand whether it will inherit the working directory, or be the directory that contains cmd.exe.) I suggest you specify the working directory for the new process using `ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory`.

(As an aside, I personally find it cleaner to create a new `ProcessStartInfo` an populate that - C# object initializers make this particularly nice) and then call `Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo)` to start it. Otherwise it looks like there's already a process when there isn't really one yet. Just MHO though, and unrelated to the problem you're investigating, probably.)

Comment: Awesome! I didn't realize that the working directory might be different when starting it this way.  I changed the working directory to the one with my tex file and it worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using cmd.exe as a FileName property of Process object, keep your commands in one batch file and then use that file for execution.

Also you can mention administrator's privilages like username, password, domain etc via StartInfo property of Process class. If you use these properties I think permission problem will not come. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx) you can find more information about StartInfo property.

Hope it helps.