# ASP.net c# Unknown error (0xfffffffe)

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, cmd, iis-7.5

Being thrown on this line:

```
// Run compiler
Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("java.exe", ex);
p.WaitForExit();
```

The error:

> Error Message: Unknown error (0xfffffffe) Stack Trace: at
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo
>   startInfo)  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo
>   startInfo)  at Arcade.UploadFunctions.minifyC2Runtime(Int32 GameID) 
>   at Arcade.GameFunctions.createGame(Int32 CatID, String Name, String
>   Description, String Instructions, Int32 UserId, Int32 Width, Int32
>   Height)  at ArcadeSubmit.submitGame(Object sender, EventArgs e)  at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)  at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Everything works fine on the dev server, upload to live server and get this error.

If I catch the `ex` line just before it's executed then manually execute it in `cmd.exe` on the live server it runs fine.

Any ideas what this could be?  I've got a hunch it's a permissions issue but I'm not sure.

Comment: Permissions would be my first guess.  But... Whats the value of ex?  Have you tried with no arguments? I would expect java.exe to exit gracefully if nothing is on the command line.

Comment: @rfmodulator, I caught the ex value before it runs and manually run it in the command window and it executes fine

Comment: @rfmodulator, when I pass `""` as the arguments it throws the same error.  Thanks for helping btw :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a permission exception. [Check this link out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532769/how-to-start-a-process-as-administrator-mode-in-c-sharp), you might get your answer there.

[Extra link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223008/process-start-permissions-problem)

[One more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133379/elevating-process-privilege-programatically)

Good luck!