# Launch an application on on the server machine through Process.Start() on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've a C# asp.net webapp hosted, which should start an InternetExplorer process on the server on a button click from the client side browser.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
       Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "www.google.com");
  }
```

Unfortunately this is not working out fine for me. But when I debug this, it works.
Please help me to achieve this.

Thanks,
/Aravind

Comment: Define "not working", what do you expect this to do and what does it do. What are you trying to achieve with this, it doesn't seem like a useful thing to do.

Comment: Thanks Ben ! I meant the IExplore process is not getting started on the server machine. Acutally what I want to achieve is to start a powershell.exe and run a script there which is a very very useful thing for me.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you don't really want to start IE and obvious security issues aside; I suggest you take a look at these two:
[Running Process on Server via ASP.NET/C# on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24805751/running-process-on-server-via-asp-net-c-on-iis) and 
[Process.Start Permissions Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223008/process-start-permissions-problem)